# How do I determine whether a (Google Apps) script is being executed on New Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a Google Apps Script for Google Sheets, but it needs to run different code depending on whether it's being run on the "New" Sheets or if it's being run on one in the "Old Sheets" formats.

It's been authored on an "Old Sheet", but I want to maintain compatibility when Google updates all sheets to the "New Sheets" format. (This specifically pertains to showing an alert box to the user: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs)

Comment: As far as I know they key-structure/url of the sheet is quite different. If you check the keys you should be able to understand which sort of sheet it is.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a bit of a bodge and could stop working eventually, but you could try calling one of the functions that aren't supported by the new sheets. For example programmatically creating a trigger via newTrigger.

This code contained in a new sheet:

```
function onOpen() {

  try {

    var everySixHours = ScriptApp.newTrigger("runCommand")
        .timeBased()
        .everyHours(6)
        .create();

  } catch(e) {

      Logger.log(e);
      Logger.log('You are using a new Google sheet');
  }

  Logger.log(everySixHours);

}

function runCommand() {
  Logger.log('runCommand()');
}
```

outputs this in the log when the sheet is refreshed:

```
[14-08-10 22:15:07:767 BST] Exception: You do not have permission to call newTrigger
[14-08-10 22:15:07:767 BST] You are using a new Google sheet
[14-08-10 22:15:07:767 BST] undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could fairly reliably do this by checking the [creation date](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getDateCreated()) of the document.

Comment: That is not necessarily true since the update was optional for a while...it could be used if you have only files you created yourself. Any file created by someone else that updated earlier ( or later) would not follow the rule.

Comment: A lot of what this will be used for may be run on old Google Sheets (that are used by my company) but I want the script to be compatible with either for when new sheets are created. Any ideas?